# How to get Date only from data view _Sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

I am using this query

```
SELECT
    Convert(date,s.EventDate) as s.EventDate,
    s.JobId,
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    s.SubscriberID,
    su.EmailAddress
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN ENT._Subscribers su ON s.SubscriberKey = su.SubscriberKey
```

It works but it includes the time and because of that i cant make a filtered DE as it can only filter dates not including the time.

ie.
SentDate
Sep 27 2021 7:35AM

Comment: It might be the using of s.EventDate as the alias for your Convert. Try `CONVERT(date, s.EventDate) as EventDate` or even just `as myDate` or similar.

Comment: @Gortonington trying it now. Thank you brother.

Comment: @Gortonington the problem now is that the Sent_Date returned current dates